# Check if an object doesn't have empty string or empty array as its values

Tags: javascript

I have an object,

```
const load={trolleyNo:"",trolleyItems:[],cartType:""}
```

I need to check there aren't any empty values in this object. The array in the object should not be empty, and neither should the strings. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]  (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @rishzeta If You want to check more complex Arrays like an Array of Objects that contains different types of values you have to iterate each value to see if one of them is null or empty. Take a look at my answer too :)

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function that iterates through the keys of your object and checks if they're null and their length > 0:

```js
function isValidObject(obj) {
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] == null || obj[key].length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


const load = {
  trolleyNo: null,
  trolleyItems: [],
  cartType: ""
}

console.log(isValidObject(load));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go over the values and use `every` to check the value's length:

```js
const bad = {trolleyNo: "", trolleyItems: [], cartType: ""}
const good = {trolleyNo: "123", trolleyItems: ["cat", "hat"], cartType: "awesome"}

function isPayloadValid(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).every(v => v.length > 0);
}

console.log(`Is ${JSON.stringify(good)} valid? ${isPayloadValid(good)}`);
console.log(`Is ${JSON.stringify(bad)} valid? ${isPayloadValid(bad)}`);
```

Comment: Really nice done.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information:

If you want to check more complex arrays like an array of objects that contains different types of values, you have to iterate each value to see if one of them is null or empty.

I checked the [answer of Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346846/check-if-an-object-doesnt-have-empty-string-or-empty-array-as-its-values/76346876#76346876) and tested it on a more complex object, and then I made a function that will store every valid Object in another array named: arrayOfValidObjects.

So you don't have to deal with invalid objects after this result.

Just refer to the arrayOfValidObjects value that you need to display or change...

```js
        let arrayOfValidObjects = [];
        const Metros = [
          {
            name: 'Good Metro 1',
            note:"the oject have all the fields filled no empty string found nor null value",
            added:"this object will be added to the Array : arrayOfValidObjects",
            ride: {
              monday: { isavailable: true },
              tuesday: { isavailable: true },
              wednesday: { isavailable: true },
              thursday: { isavailable: true },
              friday: { isavailable: true },
              saturday : { isavailable: true },
              sunday : { isavailable: true }
            },
            lines: ["Bakerloo", "Central", "Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City", "Jubilee", "Metropolitan", "Northern", "Piccadilly", "Victoria", "Waterloo & City"]
          },
          {
            name: 'Bad Metro 1',
            note:"this obect contains null values",
            added:"this object will not be added to the Array : arrayOfValidObjects",
            ride: {
              monday: { isavailable: true },
              tuesday: { isavailable: true },
              wednesday: { isavailable: true },
              thursday: { isavailable: null }, // value is null
              friday: { isavailable: null }, // value is null
              saturday : { isavailable: true },
              sunday : { isavailable: true }
            },
            lines: ["Bakerloo", "Central", "Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City", "Jubilee", "Metropolitan", "Northern", "Piccadilly", "Victoria", "Waterloo & City"]
          },
          {
            name: 'Good Metro 2',
            note:"the oject have all the fields filled no empty string found nor null value",
            added:"this object will be added to the Array : arrayOfValidObjects",
            ride: {
              monday: { isavailable: true },
              tuesday: { isavailable: true },
              wednesday: { isavailable: true },
              thursday: { isavailable: true },
              friday: { isavailable: true },
              saturday : { isavailable: true },
              sunday : { isavailable: true }
            },
            lines: ["Bakerloo", "Central", "Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City", "Jubilee", "Metropolitan", "Northern", "Piccadilly", "Victoria", "Waterloo & City"]
          },
          {
            name: 'Bad Metro 2',
            note:"this obect contains an empty String",
            added:"this object will not be added to the Array : arrayOfValidObjects",
            ride: {
              monday: { isavailable: true },
              tuesday: { isavailable: true },
              wednesday: { isavailable: true },
              thursday: { isavailable: true },
              friday: { isavailable: true },
              saturday : { isavailable: true },
              sunday : { isavailable: true }
            },
            lines: ["Bakerloo", "", "Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City", "Jubilee", "Metropolitan", "Northern", "Piccadilly", "Victoria", "Waterloo & City"] // empty String in the Array
          },
          {
            name: 'Bad Metro 3',
            note:"this obect contains an empty String",
            added:"", // empty String
            ride: {
              monday: { isavailable: true },
              tuesday: { isavailable: true },
              wednesday: { isavailable: true },
              thursday: { isavailable: true },
              friday: { isavailable: true },
              saturday : { isavailable: true },
              sunday : { isavailable: true }
            },
            lines: ["Bakerloo", "Central", "Circle", "District", "Hammersmith & City", "Jubilee", "Metropolitan", "Northern", "Piccadilly", "Victoria", "Waterloo & City"]
          }
        ];

        function isPayloadValid(obj) {
            // Iterate over each value in the object
            for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
                // If the value is an object and not null, recursively call the function on that value
                if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
                    if (!isPayloadValid(value)) {
                        // If the recursive call returns false, propagate the false result upward
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    // If the value is a primitive type (string, number, boolean, etc.)
                    // Check if it's an empty string or null
                    if (value === '' || value === null) {
                        // If it is, return false
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            // If no empty string or null value is found, return true
            return true;
        }
        let validObjString="Valid Objects added : ";
        let notValidObjString="Objects not added : ";
        for(var i=0; i<Metros.length; i++){
            const isValid = isPayloadValid(Metros[i]);
            if(isValid){
                // if valid show the Object content and store it to an Array of valid Objects
                console.log(`Object ${i} is valid? ${isValid} ${Metros[i]} no null nor empty values like "" found`);
                arrayOfValidObjects.push(Metros[i]);
                console.log(`Object ${i} added to the Array named "arrayOfValidObjects"`);
                validObjString += Metros[i].name + ", "
            }else{
                console.log(`Object ${i} is valid? ${isValid} ${Metros[i]} contains null element or an empty string ("")` );
                notValidObjString += Metros[i].name + ", "
            }
        }

        // here is the log of the Array made of the valid Objects
        console.log("valid Objects : " + validObjString.substring(validObjString.lastIndexOf(", "),0));
        console.log("not valid Objects : " + notValidObjString.substring(notValidObjString.lastIndexOf(", "),0));
        console.log("valid values in arrayOfValidObjects are : ");
        console.log(`List of validobject = ${JSON.stringify(arrayOfValidObjects)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns true if any value in the object is empty:

```
hasEmptyKeys = function(obj) {
    for (i in obj) {
        if (obj[i].length == 0) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```